# Lean touch in Vuforia + Unity zooms all the models to which script is attached But I want only one to zoom .?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I'm using Vuforia and unity for my AR App. which has more than 2 models/image targets. To zoom in and out I used Lean Touch.
But the problem is both will get zoom on pinching .
I want only one to zoom which is currently detected.. OR
 
I want reset Scale component of my 3D model/models on OnTrackingLost() function in DefaultTrackableEventHandler so that when it detects other one it shows on original scale (as i set max sim images detected to one).
Thanks !﻿

Comment: You just [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42985000/reset-scaling-of-models-in-image-target-in-unity-and-vuforia/42987290#42987290) this a few hours before.

Comment: Yes , sorry I asked it twice ...marked as duplicate