# Reset scaling of models in image target in unity and vuforia

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

[image]I'm using Vuforia and unity for my AR App. which has more than 2 models/image targets. To zoom in and out I used Lean Touch.
But the problem is both will get zoom on pinching .
I want only one to zoom which is currently detected.. OR
I want reset Scale component of my 3D model/models on OnTrackingLost() function in DefaultTrackableEventHandler so that when it detects other one it shows on original scale (as i set max sim images detected to one).
Thanks !

**EDIT :**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class rscale : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.V)) {
            transform.localScale = new Vector3 (4f, 4f, 4f);
            Debug.Log("scaling to 4");
        }
    }
}
```

BUT THIS SIMPLE SCRIPT IS ALSO NOT WORKING ?

Answer (score 0):

Your method doing the scaling, add :

```
if(this.gameObject.activeSelf == false){ return; }
// Scaling process
```

So if you run the code on all objects, only the active ones will be affected. Considering you deactivate the object on lost tracking.

Comment: All are active on Initialization !

Comment: It's all due to animator component ... I removed animator component and attached it to new game object ... But then new problem arises...please have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43029721/animate-object-when-its-animator-is-in-different-gameobject

Answer (score 0):

The trouble here is that Vuforia doesn't deactivate the 3D object attached to the image target, it only deactivates his renderer component and the colliders so you can't put a filter asking for the active state of the game object as @Everts sugest.

Instead you can have an script where you have a public reference to both 3D game objects and a method where you set the scale of both objects to one, every time you lost your image target you should call that function and both game objects will be his scale set to one.

Another solutios is, Vuforia knows wich marker found so when you detect a marker you can activate set that game object to be the one to suffer the scale efects.

Comment: Indeed, if you use the DefaultTrackableEventHandler, it does. I tend to rewrite them so it deactivates the object instead.

Comment: I simple attached a c# script rescale to my 3d Model :
`using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class rscale : MonoBehaviour {

 // Use this for initialization
 void Start () {
  
 }
 
 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update () {
  if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.V)) {
   transform.localScale = new Vector3 (4f, 4f, 4f);
   Debug.Log("scaling to 4");
  }
 }
}`
but this is also not working  ?

Comment: Give me the solution to take the initial value of all the 3D models (say 10) and on OnTrackingLost() call reset them to their initial values..

See edited questioin

Comment: @nitesh where do you put that code? In the 3D object or in te Marker? Once you press V, in the inspector there's no change in the scale of the object that has the script attached?

Comment: @SalvadorLemus I put that code in 3D model attached (child) of image target. It works only once ..I click on play button and if i press "v" then it sets it to 4 but not after that i.e if i change the scale then it remains to that ..It is called only once .. See attached pic in edited question

Comment: As I come to know from various forms that if animator component is attached to object then some behavior are wierd. As i attached Leanrotate script to object , its not working but when i disable animator then its working fine.. dont know what to do... I have an animator attached and when we touch object (using raycast) it animates the object.I'm Totally stucked

Comment: It's all due to animator component ... I removed animator component and attached it to new game object ... But then new problem arises...please have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43029721/animate-object-when-its-animator-is-in-different-gameobject